# Maximum cardinality matching on DAGs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, matching

A question on computational complexity and graph theory. The problem of finding **maximum cardinality matchings** of undirected graphs (the largest selection of edges such that each vertex is "touched" at most once) is well-known and studied, and has a easy-to-implement cubic time solution.

Information are very sparse for the case of directed acyclic graphs, however. I am trying to find an entry point in literature for a problem related to maximum matching on **DAGs**:

Is there any algorithm that, given a DAG, finds the maximum matching that **lies on a path**? For instance, for the DAG with nodes $\{x, y, z, w\}$ and arcs $\{(x, y), (y, z), (z, w), (x, w)\}$, the set of arcs $\{(y, z), (x, w) \}$ is a maximum cardinality matching. However, it does not lie on a path (the "valid" maximum matching would be, in this case, $\{(x, y), (z, w)\}$).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  I see two different questions here.  I suggest that you ask them separately, by editing the second one out of this post, and asking a new question with the second question.

Comment: Edited the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A matching that lies on a path of length (number of edges) $m$ has at most $m+1$ vertices, and therefore at most $\lceil m/2\rceil$ edges; conversely, such a path does include a matching with $\lceil m/2\rceil$ edges, namely the one obtained by taking every other edge of the path. Thus, in order to find a maximum matching on a path, it is enough to find a longest path, and this can be done in linear time (in a unit-cost RAM model) by straightforward dynamic programming, see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs).

For the second (now deleted) problem, the answer is exactly a longest path, by the same argument (assuming you still want the not-quite-matching to be included in a path; this was not clear from the decription).

Comment: I feel a bit silly for not realizing this. Thank you for your answer!